# Converting array to a generic list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I have created a new struct that represents a linked list and two functions `listDestroy` and `arr2list`. The second function gets a generic array and converts it into a list. The code:

```
typedef struct List {
    struct List* next;
    void *value;
} List;

void listDestroy(List* list, void freeElement(void*)) {
    while(list != NULL) {
        freeElement(list->value);
        struct List* temp_node = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(temp_node);
    }
}


void* arr2list(void* array[], int length, void* copyElement(void*), void freeElement(void*)) {
    if (length == 0 || !copyElement || !freeElement) {
        return NULL;
    }

    struct List* head = (struct List*) malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    if (head == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    List* current_node = head;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        current_node->value = copyElement(array[i]);
        struct List* new_node = (struct List*) malloc(sizeof(struct List));
        if (new_node == NULL) {
            listDestroy(head, freeElement);
            return NULL;
        }
        current_node->next = new_node;
        current_node = new_node;

    }
    return head;
}
```

I think that I have a problem with the `copyElement(array[i]);`. I want to pass a generic array of elements to `arr2list` but I'm not sure if `void* array[]` is the right way. If I change it to be `void* array` I get an error for `array[i]`. What is the right way to make it work?  Is it possible to also show a working example?

Comment: How will you know what type of value `current_node->value` holds, when converting generic list to specific type array?

Comment: You probably want `void **array`. If you had `void *array` and you tried to call `array[i]`, you would be attempting to dereference a void pointer. (Remember that `array[i]` is the same as `*(array + i)`). When accessing an array index, the system needs to know exactly how many bytes to skip ahead so that it can access the _i_'th member of the memory block. Type `void` itself is not a usable type and it has no size, so this would cause an error since the system does not know how many bytes to use for the offset.

Answer (score 1):

The last node of the list ends up with a NULL next and a garbled value. I don't think this is what you wanted. Try this loop:

```
struct List* head = NULL;
struct List** tail = &head;

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    *tail = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    if (*tail == NULL) {
        listDestroy(head, freeElement);
        return NULL;
    }
    tail[0]->value = copyElement(array[i]);
    tail = &(tail[0]->next);
}
*tail = NULL;

return head;
```

This uses a pointer to pointer so that we can update `head` or `next` depending on where we are in the loop without an extra if condition. Note that the allocaction of `head` is inside the loop now, so we always allocate exactly as many nodes as we need.

Comment: I get "Passing `'void'` for parameter of incomplete type `'void *'` for `array[i]`. Also why did you use `List**`?

Comment: @vesii: Ah; Change your `void *array[]` to `void **array`.

Comment: I see. I guess you mean `tail = &(*tail)->next;` instead of ` tail = &tail->next;`. Can you provide a working example? I can't seem to how `copyElement`  should look like

Comment: @vesii: It is impossible from the question to say what `copyElement` should look like.

Comment: if the array is for example of ints, I guess it should copy regularly but should it look like?

Comment: @vesii: Your prototype for `copyElement` constrains the array to being a pointer to something.

Comment: @vesii See my answer for an example and code that combines these two answers.

Comment: @Joshua Good answer! I hope you don't mind if I included some of your fixes in my example (I get a segmentation fault otherwise). If you do, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

`void* array[]` is completely valid in this scenario, although I don't see the point of `copyElement`.
Perhaps just remove it and use `array[i]` instead?

I'd also like to point out a few mistakes that you may want to fix in your code:

Don't cast the result of `malloc` and use `sizeof(*var)` instead of `sizeof(type)`. They're unneeded and may cause issues later on if you change the type of `head`. So, change this (and any later occurrences):

```
    struct List* head = (struct List*) malloc(sizeof(struct List));
```

to this:

```
    struct List* head = malloc(sizeof(*head));
```

Consider returning `struct List *` from `arr2list`. Change this:

```
void* arr2list(void* array[], int length, void* copyElement(void*), void freeElement(void*)) {
```

to this:

```
struct List* arr2list(void* array[], int length, void* copyElement(void*), void freeElement(void*)) {
```

Also, use either `struct List *` or `List *`. Inconsistencies may make it hard to understand your code.

It may be clearer if you pass function pointers to your functions instead of just functions. So, instead of doing this:

```
returntype func(params),
```

do this:

```
returntype (*func)(params),
```

You may also want to change `malloc` calls to `calloc` calls. `calloc` zeroes out memory, which can help in debugging. Change:

```
malloc(...)
```

to:

```
calloc(1, ...)
```

---

Here's an example combining code fixes from Joshua's post and mine:

`list.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct List {
    struct List* next;
    void *value;
} List;

void listDestroy(struct List* list, void (*freeElement)(void*)) {
    while(list != NULL) {
        freeElement(list->value);
        struct List* temp_node = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(temp_node);
    }
}

struct List* arr2list(void* array[], int length, void (*freeElement)(void*)) {
    struct List* head = NULL;
    struct List** tail = &head;

    if (length == 0 || !freeElement) {
        return NULL;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        *tail = calloc(1, sizeof(struct List));
        if (*tail == NULL) {
            listDestroy(head, freeElement);
            return NULL;
        }
        tail[0]->value = array[i];
        tail = &(tail[0]->next);
    }
    *tail = NULL;

    return head;
}
```

`test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "list.c"

void free_element(void *el)
{
        free(el);
}

int main(void)
{
        List *list;
        int ctr;
        void *array[4];
        for(ctr = 0; ctr < 4; ctr++)
        {
                /* Don't usually pass sizeof(type) to malloc(),
                 * but these are extenuating circumstances. */
                array[ctr] = malloc(sizeof(int));
                if(!array[ctr]) return 1;
                *(int *)array[ctr] = ctr * 4;
        }
        list = arr2list(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]), free_element);
        while(list)
        {
                printf("%d\n", *(int *)list->value);
                list = list->next;
        }
        listDestroy(list, free_element);
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 0
> 4
> 8
> 12
> ```

---

One last note: you may consider creating a header file that defines these structures and functions (and remove the structure from `list.c`). Here's an example:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H 1

typedef struct List { // Remove this from list.c
    struct List* next;
    void *value;
} List;

void listDestroy(struct List*, void (*)(void*));

struct List* arr2list(void* [], int, void (*)(void*));

#endif
```

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! I need to combine the `copyElement` in order to "copy" the elements properly but I'm not sure how to make it work with array of `ints`. Any ideas?

Comment: @vesii My example and the fixed code that I provided copy the addresses of the `int`s, however, I could create something that duplicates them. I didn't think that necessary here.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to implement it? because I'm not sure it's possible to 'duplicate' ints or am I missing something?

Comment: @vesii You can just use `malloc(sizeof(int));` and copy the memory over: `int *p = malloc(sizeof(*p)); *p = *(int *)el; return p;`